# itext 7: converting HTML to PDF fails when using landscape mode in some cases (test repo link included)

Tags: itext7

I created a small GitHub repo that demonstrates the problem:

See https://github.com/abrighton/itext-bug.

The repo contains a generated HTML file (TEST.html) that causes itext 7 to throw an exception when converting to PDF in landscape mode:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AreaBreakRenderer.draw(AreaBreakRenderer.java:83)
        at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.drawChildren(AbstractRenderer.java:855)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.draw(BlockRenderer.java:580)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer.drawChildren(AbstractRenderer.java:855)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.draw(BlockRenderer.java:580)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.DocumentRenderer.flushSingleRenderer(DocumentRenderer.java:147)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.processRenderer(RootRenderer.java:380)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.shrinkCurrentAreaAndProcessRenderer(RootRenderer.java:369)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.shrinkCurrentAreaAndProcessRenderer(HtmlDocumentRenderer.java:347)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:264)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.processWaitingElement(HtmlDocumentRenderer.java:234)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.close(HtmlDocumentRenderer.java:194)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:135)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:261)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:221)
    at ItextBug$.saveAsPdf(ItextBug.scala:15)
    at ItextBug$.delayedEndpoint$ItextBug$1(ItextBug.scala:23)
    at ItextBug$delayedInit$body.apply(ItextBug.scala:9)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:73)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:553)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:551)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:921)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:73)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:71)
    at ItextBug$.main(ItextBug.scala:9)
    at ItextBug.main(ItextBug.scala)
```

Here is the code:

```scala
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, FileOutputStream, OutputStream}
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.{PdfDocument, PdfWriter}

// Run this from the directory containing TEST.html
object ItextBug extends App {
  def saveAsPdf(out: OutputStream, html: String, orientation: String): Unit = {
    val pageSize = if (orientation == "landscape") PageSize.LETTER.rotate() else PageSize.LETTER
    val writer: PdfWriter = new PdfWriter(out)
    val document: PdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer)
    document.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize)
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes()), document)
    out.close()
  }

  val html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("TEST.html")))
  val out = new FileOutputStream("TEST.pdf")

  // This version crashes
  saveAsPdf(out, html, "landscape")

  // This version works
//  saveAsPdf(out, html, "portrait")
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

I have only seen this happen on certain input HTML files. There could be something odd in there, however the HTML displays fine in the browser. Browsers don't throw exceptions for bad HTML and the HTML to PDF converter probably should not either, assuming that is the problem.

(Uses Scala-2.13.1, Java-11)

Comment: *"I have only seen this happen on certain input HTML files."* - In that case please share a HTML file to reproduce the issue with. If people cannot reproduce your issue, they hardly can help you.

Comment: *"Browsers don't throw exceptions for bad HTML and the HTML to PDF converter probably should not either, assuming that is the problem"* - indeed browsers usually ignore or repair some bad input which is ok as there is a user in front of them who usually will recognize if that repair results in garbage. But do you really want a HTML-to-PDF converter output garbage PDFs which automatically are forwarded to many targets? I would assume otherwise, bad html input should result in a processing break. Probably not in a `UnsupportedOperationException`, though, but something that helps find the error.

Comment: The HTML file is in the GitHub repo mentioned above (https://github.com/abrighton/itext-bug). The file is rather large, which is why I put it in the repo instead of posting it.

Comment: I tested it after transcribing the test to plain java, and indeed I could reproduce the issue. Unfortunately I'm not really into iText 7 layout routines in general, let alone HTML conversion layout, and I have no idea yet what exactly causes the issue.

Comment: The exception details made me play around with page-break settings; removing `page-break-before: always;` from `.pagebreakBefore` or `page-break-inside: avoid;` from `.nopagebreak` indeed stops the issue from occurring, but whether the issue really is in processing those styles or whether removing them simply moved some other culprit from a critical to a non-critical context, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, removing this from the CSS fixes the issue with itext 7 throwing an exception:
.nopagebreak {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
} - Thanks.